# SimpleDateFormat: hours are HH after parsing

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a `String` which is `2013-8-25, 16:33`, now I need to convert it into `Date`. For this purpose I use:

```
Date mDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm").parse("2013-8-25, 16:33");
```

Then I need to get a `String` of proper pattern, which is

```
private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
```

and here is how I do it:

```
  public static String convertDateToString(Date date) {
        String string = DateFormat.format(DATE_PATTERN, date).toString();
        Logger.logVerbose(TAG, "Date converted into String is " + string);
        return string;
    }
```

but:

```
Date converted into String is 2013-08-25THH:33:00.SSSZ
```

Why hours are still `HH`? Thanks!

Comment: What is `format` here? It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (Note that the parsing part should be irrelevant - just use `new Date()` to create a sample `Date` to format.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've corrected the code snippet.

Comment: That's still not valid code. There's no static `format` method on `DateFormat`. Again, please show a short but complete program. We should be able to copy it into a new text file, compile, and run it with no further changes. (My guess is that your DATE_PATTERN string isn't actually that, but we can't know until you've given us something to reproduce it.)

Comment: Seems the milliseconds part is also SSS...

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're right, the DateFormat is from `import static android.text.format.DateFormat.format`

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. In particular, knowing that you're not using `SimpleDateFormat` is important. Now, what version of Android are you running this on?

Comment: It is android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#HOUR_OF_DAY in this class you are supposed to use k, not H

Comment: The problem is in your formatting part, not in the `parsing` part  using `SimpleDateFormat`. Why don't you also format the date using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you're running into a compatibility issue with [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html). In particular, from the documentation:

> The format methods in this class implement a subset of Unicode UTS #35 patterns. The subset currently supported by this class includes the following format characters: acdEHhLKkLMmsyz. Up to API level 17, only adEhkMmszy were supported. Note that this class incorrectly implements k as if it were H for backwards compatibility.

I suggest you use `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting, to avoid this issue.